# Find entry from Datatable

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a WinForm with TextBox inside.
When I activate `TextBox.Leave` event what I need is to check that entry `TextBox.text` in my `DataSet` (Column, not Row) is that entry existing, if not I just have to get a `MsgBox("The text you entered already exists, use another one")` and it should not be allowed to submit that into DataBase.

Comment: You could try putting the values in the column into a list and then using the List.Contains in an IF statement.

Comment: @JonathonCowley that would be extremly slow process since the table has more then 250.000 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, I reproduce it for you it is working fine... Double Check your values what you enter in textbox...

```
Public Class Form1
Dim table As DataTable
Dim ds As DataSet
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave

    Dim result() As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Select("Name = '" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "'")
    If (result.Length > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Value Exist")
    Else
        'do your calculation
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    table = New DataTable("Players")

    ' Add two columns.
    table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)))
    table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("age", GetType(String)))
    ds.Tables(0).Select()

    table.Rows.Add("Magesh", "25")
    table.Rows.Add("flook", "22")
    ds.Tables.Add(table);


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: try to post your code inside textbox leave event, specify the value what you enter in textbox and dataset value

Answer (score 0):

you can write the sql query as select cols from tablename where col='yourtextboxvalue'
execute a datareader using commandObject.executeReader and execute dataReader.Read() method in try block. if value doesn't exist it will go to catch block and show the messagebox there.
similar thing to check for username

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Password from tblUser where UserName=@username", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);     //add parameter to the query

 if (dataReader.Read())      //if any record is available
            {
                dbPassword = dataReader["Password"].ToString();     //get the password for entered username
                if (dbPassword != "" && dbPassword.Equals(password))        
                {

                }

                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password","Invalid input");
                connection.Close();     //close the connection
            }

            else 
                MessageBox.Show("Username not found", "Invalid input");     //message will be shown if no record found for the entered user ie.username doesn't exist
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without going to Server and to prevent using server because of speed, since in my case I already have filled Dataset with all informations.

Answer (score 0):

From database perspective, the easiest way to prevent duplicate entries into a column is if you set a unique constraint on the given column:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
Id int NOT NULL,
Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT uc_Name UNIQUE (Name)
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without going to Server and to prevent using server because of speed, since in my case I already have filled Dataset with all informations.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside textbox1 leave event

```
Dim result() As DataRow = DataTable.Select("ColumnName = '" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "'")
```

and if result.length > 0 then don't save it....

Comment: Shouldn't I say what is the name of my DataSet also?

Comment: Can you retrieve your Datatable from Dataset? then Do check your datatable.select(yourcolumnname = textbox.text)

Comment: I think I have to specify my `DataSet` first in this case?

Comment: use like this dataset.Tables(0).Select

Comment: or  `dataset.Tables("tablename")`

Comment: I've tried this:
 Dim result() As DataRow = dsPrikazi.Tables("SIN_Clanovi").Select("BrClanskeKarte = '" + TextBox3.Text.Trim() + "'")
        If result.Length.ToString > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Clan sa ovim brojem clanske karte vec postoji!")
            Me.TextBox3.Focus()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
It's not working.

Comment: any exception? or result() return zero?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention DataSet Try this (Dataset is not a table but a collection of table/s)

```
Dim Tot() as DataRow = yourDataset.Tables("tableName").Select("theColName= '" + TextBox.Text.Trim() + "'")
```

or

```
Dim Tot() as DataRow = yourDataset.Tables(IndexNumberOfTable).Select("theColName= '" + TextBox.Text.Trim() + "'")
```

Comment: I have tried this:  
Dim Tot() As DataRow = Me.DataSet.DataTab;e.Select("Column= '" + TextBox3.Text.Trim() + "'")
        If Tot.Length.ToString > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Clan sa ovim brojem clanske karte vec postoji!")
            Me.TextBox4.Focus()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If 
And it just leave text.box as everything is fine.

Comment: See updated just forgot the .Tables in dataset class.